# Trim function usage

Tags: trim

I have one label field max characters allowed is 200. If the string in the label goes above 30  means, I need to trim the value and display the trimmed value.

If I go for editing means, all the 200 characters should be passed in the text box for edit.

label.Text = label.Text.Substring(0, 30) + "..."; //This is displayed in the label

After that i want to edit, for that i need to recover the full string(200 char) in the label, is it possible?

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: I need to get the full string(200 characters) when I go for editing..

Comment: The language is asp.net or c#.

Comment: Add the code you have so far so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

## TRIM function

Trim eliminates leading and trailing whitespace. We need to remove whitespace from the beginning or ending of a string. We use the .NET Framework's Trim method to do this efficiently. This method removes any characters specified.

**Trim input and output**

```
String input:       "   This is an example string. "<br>
Trim method result: "This is an example string."

String input:       "This is an example string.\r\n\r\n"<br>
Trim method result: "This is an example string."
```

So it's depend upon your label strings